Adjusting N Values Proportionally to (e.g.) Their Reciprocals, Ensuring They Stay Non-Negative
I have $N$ non-negative values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ that sum to a value slightly greater than a constant $C$. Specifically, the sum exceeds $C$ by a small margin $v$:
$\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i = C + v \hspace{1cm};\hspace{1cm} v\gt 0\hspace{1cm};\hspace{1cm} x_i\gt 0\hspace{.2cm}\forall\hspace{.1cm}i$
I want to adjust these quantities such that their new sum is exactly $C$. To achieve this, I want to reduce each quantity by an amount $a_i$ proportional to the reciprocal of its original value. The adjusted quantities will be $\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2, \ldots, \hat{x}_N$ and must be non-negative, too:
$ \hat{x}_i = x_i - a_i  \hspace{1cm};\hspace{1cm} \hat{x}_i\gt 0\hspace{.2cm}\forall\hspace{.1cm}i$
where $a_i$ are fractions of $v$ such that:
$v = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i$
$a_i = k_i \cdot \frac{1}{x_i}$
with a suitable value for $k_i$ to be determined.
The requirements are:

$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \hat{x}_i = C$
$a_i < x_i\hspace{.2cm}\forall\hspace{.1cm}i $, that is $\hat{x}_i > 0\hspace{.2cm}\forall\hspace{.1cm}i$

How can I determine the values of $a_i$ to satisfy these conditions?
Also, here I ask for an adjusting factor that is proportional to the reciprocal, but actually it would be interesting to see how it changes if I want it to be proportional to, say, the squared reciprocal.
